# C different output for the same item in array

Tags: arrays, c

can someone please tell me why I have different output between spaces in *output*?
For me it seems like it should be the same. Because the number position of item in array is same. Is it not?

I am using cuda compiler btw.

**output**

```
0, 1, 2, 3,
0, 1, 2, 3,

0, 1, 0, 1
2, 3, 0, 0
```

**code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE_POP 2
//#define SIZE_IND 40   //Fixed length
//#define SIZE_PL 10
#define N_GEN 1
int main(){

    size_t sizePop = 4 * SIZE_POP * sizeof(int8_t);
    int8_t *population = (int8_t *)malloc(sizePop);

    if(population == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate host memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_POP; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            *(population + i*SIZE_POP + j) = j;
            printf("%d, ", *(population + i*SIZE_POP + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(population + 0),*(population  + 1),
        *(population  + 2),*(population  + 3));
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", *(population  + 4),*(population  + 5),
        *(population  + 6),*(population  + 7));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to print  the value of `i * SIZE_POP + j` every cycle. It will explain your issues.

Comment: Thank you @Serge. It explains a lot.

Comment: `int` is not the same as `int8_t`

Comment: @Happy Green Kid Naps, thank you for your comment. I know that difference among ```int``` and ```int8_t``` are number of bites. The problem in my code was that I did not properly initialize array. Instead ```SIZE_POP``` should be *number of colum*, in my case 4.